# Predict response variables from rpart classification tree

Tags: r, tree, classification, rpart

I've generated a classification tree using the rpart package in R, plotted it, pruned it and tested it against my training data. I now have about 50,000 rows of data to run through the tree and want each row of explanatory variables classified, in a separate "response" column,  as one of the response variables so that I can then use that in further analysis. How do I ask R to generate that extra column?

Comment: Try with `predict(model, new_data)`... Like here: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/rpart/html/predict.rpart.html and than paste it to your `data.frame`. Ex. `df$response <- predict(...)`

Comment: Perfect, thank you Marta!